# What's the cleanest way for assigning a new pandas dataframe column to a single value?

Tags: pandas

Working with a dataframe `df` I wanted to create a new column `A` and assign it to a single value (a string in my case)

```
df['A'] = value
```

gave a warning and suggested to use loc

however the solution below still gave the same warning:

```
df.loc[:,'A']=value
```

Doing some research I found the solution below which does not generate a warning:

```
df=df.assign(A =value)
```

Is it the general accepted way of creating a new column and assigning it to a value? Are there other possibilities using loc?

pandas version '0.20.1'

EDIT: this is the warning message obtained for the 2 first methods

```
"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"
```

Comment: You did something prior to that line, did you slice or sub-select your original df and assign to `df` prior to the first line?

Comment: I like using df.assign because it creates a copy of the original dataframe, where as the other two mentioned are modifying the original dataframe itself, therefore making it hard to go back and troubleshoot.

Comment: df was derived as a boolean indexing from another dataframe (which had a different name)

Comment: well there's your answer, so the question is now are you intending to modify the original df or you want to work on a copy?

Comment: @EdChum I don't mind what will happen to the dataframe from which df was derived prior to the first line above. can you kindly explain a bit more? why doesn't the suggested .loc method remove the warning.

Comment: in your assignment to `df` prior to that line using some mask you need to take a copy : `df = some_other_df[boolean_mask].copy()` then you won't get the warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @EdChum and @ScottBoston

Since df was derived using a mask on some original dataframe

```
df = df_original[boolean_mask]
```

to avoid the warning with the two first methods, use instead `df=df_original[boolean_mask].copy()`

`df.assign` does not need this because it automatically creates a copy of the original dataframe